# How can I change a table into an endless scrolling format?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, scroll

I'm a beginner in front-end development, and I'm currently working on a website for a team project.  Initially, I designed a simple table to display user names, view counts, and like counts. However, I've since changed my plan. I now want to implement endless scrolling for my project. Could you please teach me how to do that?

Here is my first design and code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd6d2.png)

apologize for not providing any information in my initial question.
I will ensure to include more information in my future queries.

Comment: share more details here in order to give answer.

Comment: No. You're expected to make an effort and do your own research. When you have a specific issue that your research can't seem to resolve, come back and post the minimal reproducible code for the issue and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: I've updated the code information. Please check it!

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77393400/edit). Thanks in advance.